# popup.html view not updating the newly assigned values of $scope variables in controller in popup.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build an extension that scrapes email IDs from a webpage. The problem is that...

The **popup.html view** is not updating the new values of *$scope.emailList* and *$scope.count* in the controller in **popup.js**. However, when I do *Inspect Popup* it displays the new values attached to the *$scope* variables but I see no errors that I can look into and work on.

**popup.js**

```
var app = angular.module('emailScraper',[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    //Fetch URL of current Tab open in Chrome
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
        var tab = tabs[0];

        $scope.cpUrl = tab.url;
        console.log($scope.cpUrl); //I SEE ONLY THIS LINE WHEN I INSPECT POPUP
    });

    $scope.appLoaded = false;   
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("Message received: ", request); //I SEE ONLY IN Inspect Popup BUT NOT IN popup.html view

        $scope.emailList = request;
        $scope.count = Object.keys($scope.emailList).length;
        console.log("Emails found: " + $scope.count); //I SEE ONLY IN Inspect Popup BUT NOT IN popup.html view
        $scope.appLoaded = true;

        sendResponse({status: "Received JSON data!"});
    });

}]);
```

**content script** - relevant portion

```
var jsonData = scrape(); // scrape() is included in the Content Script which I've chosen to leave out here. 
console.log(jsonData);

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(jsonData, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**background.js**

```
var background = {
    injectScript: function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "myscript.js"});
        });
    }    
};

background.injectScript();
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="emailScraper">
    <head>
        <!--
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/concise-v3.4.0-UI-dist/concise.min.css">
        -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/materialize/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app/popup.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div id="popWindow">
            <div class="navbar-fixed">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        <h5 class="brand-logo">Email Scraper</h5>
                        <span class="badge">
                            <a># found </a>
                            <a>{{count}}</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="progress" ng-hide="appLoaded">
                <div class="indeterminate"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="progress" ng-show="appLoaded">
                <div class="determinate" style="width: 100%"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="collection" ng-if="count > 0">
                <a href="#modal1" data-target="modal1" class="collection-item" ng-repeat="email in emailList"><h6>{{email}}</h6></a>
            </div>

            <div ng-if="count === 0">
                <p class="flow-text">&nbsp;Sorry, No Email IDs found.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular_1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/materialize/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your comment for `console.log` suggests you may not know that the popup, the webpage with your content script, and the background page all are separate window objects with separate console logs.

Comment: Yes they are all separate but shouldn't it still work? I get to see the `console.log`s but the view isn't changing at all.

Comment: Well, I'm just worried that you've missed that basic bit of the extension architecture, moreover there's no content script code in your question, so I can't tell what's wrong. Maybe someone else will venture a lucky guess.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, I've been doing things in a haste for the last few days. I've added the content script and background.js. You can take a look.

Comment: So you inject the content script just one time when the background page is initialized, not from the popup script. From what I see, I'd say you don't need a background page at all, instead inject the content script from inside the popup script so that it's injected every time the popup is opened.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hey, I tried doing that. I added `injectScript` function and then **called** that inside the controller of **popup.js**. Now whenever I click the extension and do *Inspect Popup* I get the `console.log` messages but again **nothing happens to the view**. I also added `web_accessible_resources` in **manifest** file and set the value in the array with the name of the content script file and I also added a copy of the content script in the extensions root directory. Am i still missing out on anything? I get no errors in the console however like before.

Comment: And yeah I added the **copy** of the content script in the root directory because all my js files were in js folder so I just copied the content script in the root directory. The browser console in current page displays the `console.log`s in content script correctly.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you help me out brother? I really need to work my way around this bug. Everything should have been working fine but I really can't find a way to go past this issue.